# User sessions/authentication using GO/Gin

Tags: go, session, session-cookies

[Pet Project] I'm using Gin framework with [github.com/gin-contrib/sessions](https://github.com/gin-contrib/sessions) and [github.com/gin-contrib/sessions/cookies](https://github.com/gin-contrib/sessions/cookies). None of the pages should be accessed if you are not logged in(except sign in/up). How to check if user is logged in or not? I find `sessions/cookies` documentation quite poor(my opinion). Any help with that? Or a better choice to check sessions?

I am able to store a session, yet I don't understand how it actually is stored, where and what information is saved. By what do sessions differ and why am I still able to access pages if I set `authenticated="false"`?

Storing a sessions:

```
func StoreSession() gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        session := sessions.Default(c)

        session.Set("authenticated", "true")
        session.Save()
    }
}
```

Checking a session:

```
func CheckSession() gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        session := sessions.Default(c)

        if session.Get("authenticated") != "true" {
            c.AbortWithStatus(http.StatusUnauthorized)
        }

        c.Next()
    }
}
```

Logging out:

```
func Logout() gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        session := sessions.Default(c)

        session.Set("authenticated", "false")
        session.Save()
    }
}
```

I feel like I'm using sessions quite incorrectly, although I don't find definitions in documentation or how should I use them in a correct way. Any help, tips or articles related to that topic?